# How to make a line disappear as an object passes over it?

Tags: plotting, graphics

We are to graph a line but we want it to disappear, only making the segment the object passed over invisible. Does anyone have any suggestions or commands they recommend using?

Answer (score 4):

```
disk = Disk[];
line[y_] := InfiniteLine[{{1, y}, {2, y}}];

Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics /@ {{Red, line[y]}, disk}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}], {y, 1, -1}]
```

[image]

---

On the contrary:

```
inter[y_] := RegionIntersection[disk, line[y]]

Manipulate[Graphics[{disk, Red, inter[y]}], {y, 1, -1}]
```

[image]